# LiteralPath option for cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

In most example that I see in tutorials and books, the -LiteralPath option is almost never used by default (the -Path option seems to be preferred). Because the -LiteralPath option allows to use reserved characters (e.g. []), I don't understand why it is not used more often (if not, all the time). Is it because it is preferred to escape reserved characters manually, because it has a high performance cost, because not all cmdlet support this option or because something else?

Comment: My guess: Because it's shorter to type :) Sounds silly, but in most cases using Path works just fine, and it's shorter to type. I only use LiteralPath if I have to.

Comment: But tab completion negates that issue...

Answer (score 7):

One thing to consider is that `-Path` is most likely to be the parameter that used when a string is passed in through the pipeline.

Looking at the `Get-Item` cmdlet for instance:

> ```
> -LiteralPath <string[]>
>
> Required?                    true
> Position?                    Named
> Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName)
> Parameter set name           LiteralPath
> Aliases                      PSPath
> Dynamic?                     false
>
> -Path <string[]>
>
> Required?                    true
> Position?                    0
> Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)
> Parameter set name           Path
> Aliases                      None
> Dynamic?                     false
> ```

Piping a string gets you `-Path`. Your object(s) would have to have a `LiteralPath` (or `PSPath`) property for `Get-Item` to use it. If your object has both, `-Path` is used.

I guess this doesn't necessarily answer the question; it's  a bit circular to say "`-Path` is used more often because it's more popular". A better question might be, "Why doesn't `-Path` behave like `-LiteralPath` in the first place?"

Comment: "Why doesn't -Path behave like -LiteralPath in the first place?" - Historically. In the beginning of PowerShell there was just `-Path`, as it is now. `-LiteralPath` was introduced later. For the sake of compatibility it was not made the default and `-Path` did not change, too.