# Folder name issue with Get-child Item Output

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem

The get-child item  does not return any value if folder name contains "[ " or  "]". Any solution for this? Ex: E:\test\new [folder]

Comment: Use [literalpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611307/literalpath-option-for-cmdlet)

Comment: Thanks man. it is working